# Python Tkinter layout using pack()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter. I'd like to write simple program and organize it using pack() method. Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import xlrd, os, sys, json

class Main():

    def __init__(self):
        global col, col1
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.title("Zliczanie ilosci spraw")
        self.master.minsize(width=800, height=600)

        plik = 'Aktualnie wybrany plik to: ' + 'Rejestr'

        text = Label(self.master, text = plik)
        text.pack(pady = 20)

        self.wyswietlanie()

    def wyswietlanie(self):
        '''Funkcja, ktora zlicza i wyswietla ilosc spraw pracownikow'''
        policzone_1 = []
        policzone_2 = []
        z = 0

        dzial1 = {
    "Pracownik1": "PRAC1", 
    "Pracownik2": "PRAC2"}

        dzial2 = {
    "Pracownik12": "PRAC12", 
    "Pracownik22": "PRAC22"}

        for nazw in dzial1:
            x = dzial1[nazw]   #nazwisko z pliku excela
            nazwisko = 0
            policzone_1.append((nazw, nazwisko))

        for nazw in dzial2:
            x = dzial2[nazw]   #nazwisko z pliku excela
            nazwisko = 0
            policzone_2.append((nazw, nazwisko))

        posortowane1 = sorted(policzone_1,key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
        posortowane2 = sorted(policzone_2,key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

        dzial3 = Label(self.master)
        dzial3.pack(side = LEFT)

        dzial4 = Label(self.master)
        dzial4.pack(side = LEFT)

        for i in posortowane1:
            wynik = '%s: %s' % (i[0], i[1]) 
            dzial1 = Label(self.master, text = wynik, font = "Verdana 10 bold")
            dzial1.pack(in_ = dzial3, padx = 200)

        for i in posortowane2:
            wynik = '%s: %s' % (i[0], i[1]) 
            dzial2 = Label(self.master, text = wynik)
            dzial2.pack(in_ = dzial4, padx = 200)

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()

glowne = Main()
glowne.run()
```

Result is as on image below:[image: Tkinter]

Why dzial1 and dzial2 are in these places (far from "text")? How can I organize dzial1, dzial2 (set them closer to each other)?

Comment: I would like to set them default next to each other (on center of the screen, below text.Label). Is it possible? I gave them padx 200 because they were stucked to left and right frame border (when dzial4.pack(side = RIGHT))

Comment: Such grid like layouts tend to be easier with the `grid()` method instead of pack.

Comment: please create a minimal working example. If this is a layout problem we don't need the spreadsheet, and we don't need the config file -- you can hard-code the values that you read from these files. Please see http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I modyfied the code. Now it is working example.